# Flutter iOS App Phone Auth Issue: [firebase_auth/web-internal-error] unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies

Tags: ios, flutter, recaptcha

I have problem with my phone auth on Flutter iOS app. **On Android everything works fine.**

When I try to log in using phone number, I will get redirected on website, but when it returns back to the application, error that says `[firebase_auth/web-internal-error] unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies` will occur.

I added `Background Mode` Capability with mode `Background Fetch` and `Remote Notifications` in my xCode project and also added Custom URL scheme like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>XXX (client Id is right)</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

How do I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift` file:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
      firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

  }
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
      if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
          print(userInfo)
          return
      }
  }

}
```